# Creating stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

what is wrong in this code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `diff`()
BEGIN
    declare max_date datetime;
    declare tday_date datetime;
    declare main_id varchar(20);

    select concat('#GNC', '3') into main_id;  #error shows here


    declare m1 int;
    declare m2 int;
    select max(order_date) into max_date from `order`;
    #select max_date;
    select curdate() into tday_date;
    select extract(month from max_date) into m1;
    select extract(month from tday_date) into m2;

    if m1 != m2 then
        TRUNCATE `grocery`.`order_seqid`;
    end if;



    select m1, m2, main_id;
END
```

It is giving error like missing end. if I remove the if statement it works fine.

Comment: If you are running this from command line, did you change the `DELIMITER`?

Comment: @deepak it will be helpful if you post the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there :) the only problem I see is *all your declarations are not at the beginning of your logic* and *you are not using delimiter* as mentioned by @Alvaro; try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `diff`()
  BEGIN
    declare max_date datetime;
    declare tday_date datetime;
    declare main_id varchar(20);
    declare m1 INT;
    declare m2 int;

    select concat('#GNC', '3') into main_id; 

     select max(order_date) into max_date from `order`;
    #select max_date;
    select curdate() into tday_date;
    select extract(month from max_date) into m1;
    select extract(month from tday_date) into m2;

    if m1 != m2 then
      TRUNCATE `grocery`.`order_seqid`;
    end if;



    select m1, m2, main_id;
  END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing delimeter ,as well as declare section does not contains any simple `SELECT` Statement.
In your code just replace

```
   declare main_id varchar(20);
    select concat('#GNC', '3') into main_id;  #error shows here
    declare m1 int;
    declare m2 int;
```

with

```
declare main_id varchar(20);
declare m1 int;
declare m2 int;
select concat('#GNC', '3') into main_id;  #error shows here
```

Try below code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `diff`()
BEGIN
    declare max_date datetime;
    declare tday_date datetime;
    declare main_id varchar(20);
    declare m1 int;
    declare m2 int;
    select concat('#GNC', '3') into main_id  ;
    select max(order_date) into max_date from `order`;
    #select max_date;
    select curdate() into tday_date;
    select extract(month from max_date) into m1;
    select extract(month from tday_date) into m2;

    if m1 != m2 then
        TRUNCATE `grocery`.`order_seqid`;
    end if;

    select m1, m2, main_id;
END
```

Hope this will helps.